# Obtaining ext4 metadata

Tags: ext4, metadata

Is there any way of obtaining the following metadata on an ext4 filesystem?

- latest modified files
- files modified during a certain period
- largest file
- files within a size range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no indexing of these values. You have to check all existing files (usually with `find`).